# Lazy properties - valid use of mutable?

Tags: c++, mutable

Today I found myself writing a bit of code like the following, and I was wondering if this is a valid use of the `mutable` keyword.

The idea is that I want to access some properties through a `const` pointer, but I only want to evaluate the properties when I need them.

```
class Person {
  public:
    Person() : age(-1) {}
    ~Person() {} 

    int GetAge() const {
      if( age == -1 ) { CalculateAge(); }
      return age;
    }

  private:
    mutable int age;

    // Note: as a result of being called from a `const` method, 
    // CalculateAge has to be const itself.
    void CalculateAge() const {
      age = 33; // do calculation based on date of birth or whatever.
    }
};
```

Is this the point of `mutable`, or am I abusing it here?
I was convincing myself with the reasoning that conceptually the above code is equivalent to

```
class Person {
  public:
    Person() {}
    ~Person() {} 

    int GetAge() const {
      // Always do the expensive calculation here
      return 33;
    }
};
```

or

```
class Person {
  public:
    Person() {
      // Do the expensive calculation here even if age is never used.
      age = 33; 
    }
    ~Person() {} 

    int GetAge() const {
      return age;
    }

  private:
    int age; // non-mutable
};
```

where `GetAge()` is correctly marked as `const`; whether it actually caches the result is an implementation detail that is irrelevant to the client of my class.

**Edit:** In addition I would be interested in hearing any other solutions that do not involve making everything non-`const`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the rationale for `mutable` in the first place.

Comment: Note that, often, `const` methods are thread-safe. This breaks that assumption, so be careful.

Comment: @Mehrdad Threading raises more issues than that: if the class has any non-const functions, client code must probably ensure synchronization on all functions.  But you're right that threading does add additional issues.

Comment: As @n.m. says, this is exactly why `mutable` was invented.  The alternative, used before `mutable` was to cast away const.  Today, this might not work (in theory, anyway), since without any `mutable`, the compiler is allowed to put the entire object into read only memory.  (In practice, the pre-mutable rule can be counted on: the compiler won't put an object with a user defined constructor in read-only memory, because the object can't be in read-only memory while the constructor runs, and systems don't offer the possibility of making the memory read-only later.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think you mean client code only has to ensure proper synchronization on all functions if it actually *uses* the non-const functions somehow, not if they merely exist. :) Which isn't the case if the client code only has a const reference to the object, because it can't call non-const functions. Unless of course it does something sneaky (with `mutable` as we see here, or `const_cast`, or something similar with an extra level of non-const indirection), hence my point...

Comment: @JamesKanze: Also I'm surprised you mentioned the point about read-only memory being safe "in practice"... if modifying const objects is undefined behavior, then isn't it completely irrelevant if the memory is read-only or not? Either way the compiler can assume it is and break your code, whether or not systems have that capability.

Comment: But if a class provides `const` functions which change `mutable` fields, then it isn't the *client*'s responsibility to make it thread-safe, is it? The class itself should then make sure that the `mutable` field is read / written consistently.

Comment: @Mehrdad Client code has to ensure synchronization everywhere if _any_ thread calls a non-const function.  Or under whatever conditions the class documents; the class could document that certain const threads also require synchronization.  (And if the class documents nothing, you have to assume that it can't be used in a multithreaded environment anyway.)

Comment: @CompuChip The class' responsibility is to document what it requires.  The standard does this globally, for all classes and functions (unless specified otherwise); the most obvious specification for a user defined class would be to conform to the standard's default, but there's nothing wrong with a class specifying something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mutable can be used if you want a method to be const because it does not change the external state of an object, but you still need to change some internal state. In my opinion this is exactly what you have here. The deferred calculation of age is just some internal optimization and it reasonable to hide that optimization from the user. The user will not understand why getting the age modifies the object ('s external state).

But: I do not like mutable. mutable can be a problem if you have a const object which resides in read-only memory (e.g. read only file mapping). If you then call a const method on that object, the compiler will not complain. But the code will crash if you modify some mutable object.

Comment: I think if the compiler allocates a const object with mutable fields in read-only memory, then that's a compiler bug...

Comment: @TamásZahola: I don't know exactly, but I hope so. But I could also imagine having a read-only file mapping or some other read-only memory. I know, theses are rare cases, but have to be kept in mind, I believe.

Comment: @TamásZahola: Looking at the standard I guess that 7.1.1.11 "The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a const specifier applied to the containing class object
and permits modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the object is const (7.1.6.1)." prohibits the compiler from putting const objects with mutable members into a const data section. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

<del>Not a complete answer, but yes, it looks like and abuse to me. You should mark `mutable` only members that do not modify the external state of the object. In your case you have a method `GetAge` which exposes the member `age` which means that changing `age` changes the “visible” state of the object.</del>

**edit**

After your edits, I have to say that it is ok. As long as you use the member `age` like a `cache`.